# Setting up an Oracle db role with grant selects - 'table does not exist'

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two users, ADAM1 and ADAM2. I want to create a role that gives read-only access / select only to ADAM2 to the tables in ADAM1.

As ADAM1 I did this:

```
create role ECN_READ_ONLY not identified;
grant select on ADAM1.T_ADMIN to ECN_READ_ONLY;
grant ECN_READ_ONLY to ADAM2;
```

And then in ADAM2 I did this:

```
select * from ADAM1.T_ADMIN; 
--Error! table does not exist.

select * from USER_ROLE_PRIVS where USERNAME = 'ADAM2'; 


USERNAME=ADAM2
GRANTED_ROLE=ECN_READ_ONLY
ADMIN_OPTION=NO
DEFAULT_ROLE=YES
OS_GRANTED=NO

select * from ROLE_TAB_PRIVS where ROLE = 'ECN_READ_ONLY';    


ROLE=ECN_READ_ONLY
OWNER=ADAM1
TABLE_NAME=T_ADMIN
COLUMN_NAME=
PRIVILEGE=SELECT
GRANTABLE=NO
```

What went wrong?

If I just do a straight GRANT SELECT to ADAM2 then it works fine.

Comment: Are you doing this within a stored procedure?

Comment: Can you post your complete test case. http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/schema-owners-and-application-users.php

Comment: Check select * from session_roles; Maybe the user logged in before you made this grant. And he is still active.

Comment: @Brad - no, using command line.

Comment: @Multisync - great catch. That's the answer. I hadn't ever come across sessions before - thought I just had to commit :O

Comment: You should post that as an answer so it gets indexed by the search engine.  Very useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as commented by Multisync:

Check

```
select * from session_roles;
```

Maybe the user logged in before you made this grant. And he is still active